# What is the most appropriate way to handle returning errors of multiple types within a Rust function?

Tags: rust, error-handling

## Intro note

I wrote this question some time ago while I was thinking about the different possible approaches which might be used for error handling.

I don't think this turned out to be particularly useful for others, however if you are interested you can view the edit history to find these details.

I re-worked this question in March 2024, to make it more concise, and therefore, hopefully useful.

## Summary

A function in Rust might have to call several other functions, likely from different libraries. These functions will return error or success conditions using a `Result` type.

As you know, a `Result` object takes two template parameters (types).

This leads to some complexity in how to deal with the set of possible types which can be returned by a tree of function calls, at any level of the call stack.

What I mean by this is as follows: A function may return a type to represent an error condition. This function may also call other functions, which themselves may return a type to represent an error condition. Therefore, for any function, which may itself call other functions, there is a set of possible return types.This is of particular relevance to handling errors.

In other languages, these error return types might be handled dynamically. Indeed, this is also possible with Rust, but it is not necessary that the designer take such an approach.

Because we must handle a set of types, it is inevitable that we must do something to reconcile the different error types.

Here is some pseudocode to demonstrate the issue. In the below code, a function calls two other functions, which return different types to represent error cases.

```
fn someNewLibraryFunction() -> Result<OkType, Undecided> {

   let first_result: Result<Something, ErrorType1> = tryToDoThis();

   match first_result // ... // etc --> return Undecided;

   let second_result: Result<SomethingElse, ErrorType2> = tryToDoThat(first_result);

   match second_result // ... // etc --> return Undecided;

   // If we got to here, compute result and return Ok
   return Ok(SomeOkType);
}
```

## A review of Possible Approaches

Rather than detailing all possible approaches as I did previously, I will summarize the most sensible approaches.

**In order to understand the situation clearly, it is helpful to review the set of possible engineering strategies we might choose to take to solve the problem.**

1. **Log everything and return nothing:**

   This is the most simple approach, and is trivial.

   We handle all returned errors by logging them and throwing away the error. We could log using `println!` or some other more sophisticated method.

   We would not likely choose to do this beyond the prototyping stage.

   Since there is no returned error type, this solves the problem. Alternativelty, we could return `Err(())`, to indicate an error occurred, but include  no further information.
2. **Convert all error messages to a uniform type, such as String:**

   Extending the previous option, rather than returning information about an error which occured, we could coerce all errors to a string type, and return `Err(message)`.

   This solves the problem by return a uniform type. Unlike the first suggestion, we can retain some information about the error.

   This has the following advantages and disadvantages:

   - *Advantage:* The caller gets to decide what to do when an error occurs
   - *Advantage:* We can still implement branching logic, depending on what went wrong
   - *Disadvantage:* To branch, we resort to comparing strings which is inefficient and inelegant as a solution. It is not scalable or robust to software changes
   - *Disadvantage:* We don't have any type information, which would be a better solution for branching
   - *Disadvantage:* Returning a `String` as an error type doesn't indicate to the caller that what they have received is an error. Therefore it is easy to use incorrectly

   *Note: Branch means logic like `if` or `match`*
3. **Convert the possible set of error types you expect to receive into a single type:**

   There are two directions this could take:

- You could convert everything to a single type
- Or you could create a new `enum` with variants for each of the possible sources of error
- How much error handling you might do, or what errors you might group together into some new representation might vary

  This is a more Rust inspired approach.

  Imagine you build a system using some libraries, and your libraries are in layers like a Pyramid.

  You are working on a particular library layer which sits between two others. This library calls functions from one or more other libraries (lower levels of the Pyramid), and is called from the next higher layer.

  These functions which are called by this layer may return a plethora of different possible error types.

  As far as is possible, handle these errors.

  When it is not possible to do so, convert the existing error types to some new error type which is a **uniform type within your library layer**. This means that all errors which might occure are mapped to a single type.

  As mentioned above, this new type might be a single type, or it might be an enum type of multiple possible variants. In the case of the latter, the set of variants corresponds to the set of error types we are interested in reporting to higher layers of code.

  Regardless of the choice made, you have simplified a set of many possible error types from multiple different sources into a simpler type.

  Similarly to the previous case, we may lose specific type information relating to the exact source of the error if you choose to map all errors to a single type.

  If you choose to use an enum of many variants, then you will not necessarily lose information about the source of the error.

  Note the following: **You should not simply create a new enum which wraps all the possible error types which you can receive.** For example, if lower level code can report a `SpecialMathLibraryError` higher levels of code should not need to know about the type `SpecialMathLibraryError`. Instead, you should **convert** a `SpecialMathLibraryError` into some new "thing" which is related to the library layer you are writing.

  While it would appear to be simpler to simply wrap lower level error types into some ever-growing enum **I highly recommend you do not do this. You will end up with a very strong coupling throughout all levels of your code due to the dependency on the type information of errors raised from lower level code.**

  The method described here comes with a significant disadvantage, which is worth explaining. Taking this approach incurs a significant maintainance overhead, which would not be seen in other languages which use a more dynamic approach. If you want to flex your software archetecture, it takes a long time to make any required changes. Singe an API is essentially changing, all calling functions will have to be adapted, due to a breaking API change. Changing the set of possible return types in an `enum` which represents errors will also be a time consuming process with a maintainance overhead.

  - *Advantage:* We can store additional data in our type. If the type is an enum, we can branch on the fact that it can store multiple possible variants
  - *Disadvantage:* We need to implement new logic to convert from existing error types to the new type. We could do this using the `From` trait.
  - *Disadvantage:* We may combine some unrelated error types into a single new type, possibly a variant of an enum
  - *Disadvantage:* Maintenance overhead expands significantly. We have to manage a whole new `enum` type
  - *Advantage:* We can maintain the original information about the source of the error, if we choose to do so

  This also creates maintenance chaos, because if our functions change, the error types we have to handle may change. This means we need to change a whole `enum` as well as the logic of our function, and the boilerplate code for conversions.

4. **Use Dynamic Dispatch:**

   Here is an example of how we might implement something similar to a `try-catch`. It is a runtime branch depending on whether downcasting back to the original error types worked or not. The same thing can be done using `error.is::<T>()`.

   ```
   fn someNewLibraryFunction() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
       return Err(Box::new(MyError1{}));
   }

   fn main() {

       let result = someNewLibraryFunction();

       match result {

           Err(error) => {

               if let Some(downcasted) = error.downcast_ref::<MyError1>() {
                   println!("It is MyError1 type");
               }
               else if let Some(downcasted) = error.downcast_ref::<MyError2>() {
                   println!("It is MyError2 type");
               }
               else {
                   println!("Could not downcast the error");
               }

           },

           Ok(_) => {

           },

       }
   }
   ```

   As with `try-catch` in other languages, it is the callers responsibility to know what error types can be "thrown" from the called functions, and to chose to implement a handler for each of these, or not. The final `else` has the advantage of acting as a `catch-all` or `catch-any` statement.

## Summary

Unfortunatly, there isn't an obvious best way of writing error handling code in Rust.

Previous experience with OOP languages would suggest a runtime dynamic approach is best. This has the advantage of being relatively light in terms of maintainance, and relatively quick to implement. The "disadvantage" is that you have to "go and find out" what the possible error types are - the compiler will not just tell you. (Which it will if you take the enum approach.)

I don't really consider this much of a disadvantage, given that the dynamic dispatch method is universal to almost all other languages with serious industrial application. (C#, C++, Python, Java, others...)

If there are any other alternatives it would be interesting to know about them. (Just edit the question to add.)

Comment: Half the cases are completely redundant and trivial variants of others (e.g. 5/7, probably 4/6 as I've no clue what differentiates them). If you look at the ecosystem, 5/7 is what you'll find in most libraries with first-class support in libs like [`thiserror`](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror), 8 is what you'll find in most applications as etiher a `dyn Error` or something like [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/) as an application doesn't care to *produce* fine grained errors.

Comment: 4/6 (no idea how they're supposed to differ) is what'd be preferrable from a precision point of view (as 5/7 means functions claim they can return errors which they can not actually produce), but the lack of features like polymorphic variants or anonymous enums makes them a huge burden from both maintenance and navigation point of views.

Comment: Error per function approach is mainly useful when this is a public API where errors are common and likely need to be handled case by case. If your function returns enum containing only possible cases of failure, code that uses the function can handle errors exhaustively. Of course there are cases when you don't need such control and error just gives you the message useful for human, in that case dynamic dispatch is sufficient. I would not like to be forced to use logging to find out what went wrong, rather pass errors as values with useful information and leave logging to users preference.

Comment: Oh please don't downcast.  Avoiding that is 99% of the _point_ of dynamic dispatch, having a `do_something` common method that handles what you need to per-type.  If your higher-level error handling is dependent on the type of error, that's usually a deeper design problem, where your abstraction level is incorrect.  Exceptions to the rule exist, but something tells me this is **not** one of them, as presented.  If you're handling errors here, _all_ errors probably have the same action: either retry everything, or bail out.  If not, your "common point" is incorrect.

Comment: The main, and maybe only, question here is this: who is the *consumer* of those errors? Logs? Use a logger or `eprintln` to write to STDERR, doing so at whatever level of the call stack is appropriate. External callers of your code? Unless you're re-exporting the libs from your crate you should map them to error variants for your crate to hide the implementation details from consumers, and return Results of those. Note that the mapping does not need to be 1-to-1. I realize it's frustrating but this is too broad/opinionated of a question for SO.

Comment: @Masklinn In 4, reuse existing error types. In 6 define totally new error types to be used as the variants. 6 is more work, 4 seems like a bad idea, for the reasons I explain. (Not that 6 is much better.)

Comment: @KevinAnderson What would you suggest to do in the case where a function can return multiple error types? Would you bundle these into an enum? (In one of the many possible ways I described above.)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant (6) seems like completely useless overhead, it's just busy work, your explanations and examples for (4) make absolutely no sense, are you confusing enums with unions? (4) would have a variant per upstream error type, possibly with additional metadata.

Comment: @Masklinn In Rust, enum and union is effectively the same thing. Sorry it's maybe not the clearest - I don't really think either option is really good

Comment: @KevinAnderson I came back to this some time later and edited the question, read through the comments again. What would you propose to do in a non-Rust language to handle errors, except by downcasting and branching depending on the type? For example, Java, C++, Python, etc. Other than logging the "message" data from an exception, ignoring it, or handling all exceptions in the same way? I don't see what other option you have other than to downcast?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant that is a deeper error-recovery question, but the short answer is: type isn't everything.  What would you do if you were in a language where there were no types like this to help, like only error codes (int return values) in bare C?  If you restrict yourself to _only_ type, or _only_ error codes, you don't have that flexibility.  But regardless, even if you're in a class-based situation, downcasting still represents other issues, and there are better ways.  Sometimes you're in a corner though, and you have to, but you shouldn't favor it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I'm not quite sure how to respond to this other than to say I am asking specifically about languages which support downcasting in some way. It seems obvious that in a language like C such a thing wouldn't be possible... My point really is this. If you have type information, that is the most sensible way to perform a branch operation. Which, in the most general case, is something that would be required to handle an error. In C you only have values to branch on. In Rust, you have type information in two forms. Variants and downcasting. You would not branch on values.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking too broad question. All of your solutions have different tradeoffs. The only possible answer here is that "it depends on what you are doing". Do you write a library or an application? Is this error only visible internally or do you want to export it to external consumers? Are those errors  recoverable, or not and if so are all of them recoverable or only some? What caller should do when it encounters error? There is no one-answer-fit-all-sollution.

I would recommend reading source code of other rust projects and seeing what they do and trying yo understand why. You could also read some blog posts. I would recommend a great article [Modular Errors in Rust](https://sabrinajewson.org/blog/errors).

Answer (score 2):

Option 4 is quite easy if you use [`thiserror`](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror/) crate.

I think, proper way to do it:

- When error must not happen (e.g. broken internal invariant), use `unwrap` or `expect` instead of bloating your interface. burntsushi has [excellent article](https://blog.burntsushi.net/unwrap/) on topic.
- Use exact type for the function in libraries because user may need to know what went wrong. `thiserror` is great for generating error enums.
- Use some type agnostic error handling in applications because it is just easier and you know exactly how error is used. There are few variants, e.g. `Box<dyn Error>`, [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow), [`eyre`](https://crates.io/crates/eyre/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that, based on context, you'd use any one of your solutions. For an error where you need to keep the errors distinct e.g. a function that downloads a file having a file system error or a networking error, an enum would be best and would be only a few lines of code. For an errors you don't need to handle e.g. an error that will be printed to the user, you can convert it to a string-based error within the function that can easily be propagated up the call stack. All situations should boil down to these two choices. If you have a function with a large number of error types possible, your function should handle these errors (or at least compress them e.g. returning Argument/IO error rather than ZeroDivision, Networking, File System etc.), not the function above it.

I would also argue that enums don't require that much maintenance as Rust's syntax is quite concise usually resulting in one line per error type.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr:

Having given some consideration to this matter over the past few days, I have come to the conclusion that the most sensible approach is generally to use dynamic dispatch.

- **Reasons to use Enum:** If, and only if, a match expression is used to handle the type contained inside `Err`, then the compiler will object to any missing error types. I explain later why **although this appears to be an advantage, it actually isn't,** as often we don't want to handle all possible errors at all possible levels of call stack, and because the compiler cannot write error handling logic for you any more than it can write any other logic for you, so compiler assistance is the wrong tool here.
- In addition, we can circumvent the compiler behavior by ignoring the error with `let _` or by not using a match statement and using `if let` instead.
- **Reasons to use Dynamic Dispatch:** With dynamic-dispatch, we "opt-in" to the types of error we want to handle at the appropriate level of call stack. This is exactly how all other programming languages work.
- We still have to do *something* with the returned value. We still have to write `match` for `Result<T, E>`, unless we choose to ignore it as described above.
- That means we have to at least acknowledge that there was an error, even if we do nothing with it. This is usually the right behaviour.

Allow me to explain why:

## Context

The caveat to this answer is that the context in which I happen to be writing this system is as a "middleware" programmer.

What does this mean?

- I am writing a collection of processes which work together as a system, and while writing these processes I find myself needing to split out chunks of code into modules or libraries as their own crates.
- I am using a collection of external crates, one of which is the standard Rust library, but there are many others.
- I am not writing a self-contained library. What I am doing instead is writing code, which aggregates functionality from multiple existing libraries.
- This new code forms a library.
- Sometimes I (me personally) am the client, because I write an end process which uses the libraries I have written, sometimes someone else in the company is the client.

## Why *not* to use enum, in this context?

I can see why someone writing a self contained library might reach for an `enum` as the best tool to represent their error.

- There are a set of things that can go wrong in the code, and these are summarized into an `enum` which provides enough information for clients to understand what went wrong and to write debugging statements or error handling logic to recover.

*Programming Rust, 2nd Edition* states almost as much in Chapter 7: *Error Handling*, section *Declaring a Custom Error Type*. Here, a `struct` is used to represent an error which might be produced in a JSON library while parsing input. It stores an context-dependent error message, and the line and column numbers of where the parsing error occurred. An `impl` of `fmt::Display` is written, as well as an empty `impl` of `std::error::Error`. This allows the custom error to work with the Standard Library Error types.

To summarize: Using an `enum` (or `struct`) seems like a sensible choice for self-contained libraries which may emit a set of errors.

Where this goes wrong is in the calling code.

- It does not make sense to handle errors in calling code by changing the error type from one thing to another. This requires programming overhead (boilerplate code) for type conversions and to define a set of new types.
- If we were to take this approach, we would have to write 1 new error type in our calling code for every single error type which we need to handle. Put another way - for every error type returned to us by some library(ies) we must define a new type as part of an enum, if we want to take this approach.
- If we fail to do the above, for example by bundling more than one error type into a single enum variant, then we *lose type information*.
- That means that the code which calls our code can't branch on the type of error returned. We can't implement error handling further up the call stack using branching logic.

In the diagram below I attempt to sketch this out to explain.

[image: Rust enum error schema]

If it wasn't clear, here we have some middleware library (which we have written) which is used by 1 or more `fn main` processes. That middleware library defines an enum summarizing the possible errors, which occur due to each of the libraries the middleware layer depends on.

```
// Pseudocode

// From Database Wrapper Library
struct DBConnectionError;
struct DBSQLError;
struct DBQueryLogicError;
struct DBOutOfMemoryError;

// From some io library
enum IOErrorTypes {
   DiskError,
   FileNotOpenError,
   // ...
}

// From CSV library
enum CSVLibError {
    ParseError,
    FileIOError,
    UnicodeError,
    DataTypeError,
    StructureFormattingError,
}

// What we do in our middleware layer
enum MiddlewareError {
   DatabaseErrorSQL,
   GeneralDatabaseError, // bundle everything else here, lose type information
   CSVParseError,
   CSVStructureError,
   CSVDataTypeError,
   OtherCSVError, // again
   IODiskError,
   IOFileError, // again
}
```

From this, it seems pretty convincing that using an `enum` approach is the wrong thing to do, regardless of whichever of the many possible subtle variants we might choose to use.

## Arguments in favor of dynamic dispatch approach

First of all, while not in and of itself an argument in favor of this approach, the book *Rust Programming 2nd Edition* essentially describes the same thing in the section **Working with Multiple Error Types** on page 166.

Here, it is explained that the appropriate, thread safe, return type is:

```
Box<dyn std::error:Error + Send + Sync + 'static>
```

which it is suggested be aliased in this way:

```
type GenericError = Box<dyn std::error:Error + Send + Sync + 'static>;
type GenericResult<T> = Result<T, GenericError>;
```

I'm not sure if I like this personally.

This section of the book contains two important paragraphs, which I will repeat here:

> The downside of the `GenericError` approach is that the return type no longer communicates precisely what kinds of errors the caller can expect.

> If you're calling a function that returns a `GenericResult` and you want to handle one particular kind of error by let all others propagate out, use the generic method error.downcast_ref::()`. It borrows a reference to the error, *if* it happens to be the particular type of error you're looking for:

```
// Corresponding code will be shown later
```

##### First Paragraph:

To make this clearer, the book is saying you can **no longer write a match statement and expect the compiler to force you to deal with every possible error type.** The reason for this is that we are using dynamic dispatch, something which is inherently runtime behavior dependent. The compiler doesn't know at compile time what the list of possible error types are, so it can't force you to write a match branch for each of them. All it knows is the error type must be something which implements the `std::error::Error` trait. The return type is a fat pointer containing this information.

However, I would argue that this behavior is actually an *advantage* in most situations. Consider the following:

- When writing a function, do you want the compiler to force you to deal with all possible types of error at all levels of the call stack?

The answer is clearly "no". If you encounter an "out of memory" error, you can't deal with this at any level of the call stack, except perhaps the top level where you `println!("Out of memory!")` and then immediately die with `process::exit(1)`.

However, at *some* levels of the call stack you will want to implement some error handling logic for *some* types of error. This is intrinsically a *programmer* problem, which the compiler cannot solve for you. *The compiler cannot make decisions about how to handle exceptions any more than it can tell you what to write for the logic of any other function.*

Therefore, in my opinion, it is pointless to desire some structure where a `match` statement fails to compile because you did not exhaustively handle every error type.

Imagine how much extra code this would cause you to write, and how many times you would be writing this line of code:

```
match functionReturningResult() {
    Ok(ok_value) => { ... },

    Err(err) => {

        match err {
            ErrorTypeWeDontDealWithHere(error_type_we_dont_deal_with_here) => {
                return ErrorTypeWeDontDealWithHere(error_type_we_dont_deal_with_here);
            },
            // Repeated, several times, for each different type, maybe ?
            // Maybe match cases where we have actual "real" logic to deal with the error
        }

    },
}
```

##### Second Paragraph + Code:

In contrast, dynamic dispatch affords us the ability to write context-dependent and flexible logic for error handling, handling only the errors we want to, without cluttering the code with boilerplate just to keep the compiler happy.

Here's how we do it, again this example is taken from the same book.

```
match function_returning_error() {

    Ok(()) => ...

    // We are still forced to *do something* with the error or at least
    // acknowledge that we got one
    Err(err) => {

        // We "opt-in" and choose the types of error we want to implement
        // error handling logic for. The type "ErrorType" is one we can
        // handle here
        if let Some(error_value) = err.downcast_ref::<ErrorType>() {
            // Error handling logic goes here
        }

        // we can have a "catch-all" / "catch-other" else statement too
        else {
            println!("Not a type of error we handle at this level of the stack");

            // we might want to handle it at the next level of call stack?
            return Err(err);
        }
    },

}
```

## Summary

Here is a summary of reasons why one might choose to use a dynamic dispatch approach:

- Flexiblity: We can choose which errors to handle at the level of call stack where it is appropriate to handle those errors. For errors we don't want to handle at the same level, we can propagate.
- No type conversions from one error type to another. Everything is encompassed by the `dyn Error` trait.
- Fast to modify and restructure: No maintenance overhead of introducing new types, just use existing ones.

The tl;dr at the top should now make a lot more sense, too.

## One further idea - Using the `source()` field of `std::error::Error`

Without adding further explanation, I will include this (modified) snippet from the same book, which demonstrates how to write a generic "print detailed error information" function.

The idea here would be to return a new error type from library layer boundaries, where the internal error is encapsulated in the `source` field.

This would allow a middleware layer to handle all the error types that it can recover from, and propagate out a new set of "Middleware error" type(s) which encapsulate the lower level errors that it encountered but was not able to recover from. Those would be returned to the client code, which itself might be able to handle them, either with recovery logic or by printing debugging information.

The field `source` is an `Option` type, which may contain something implementing the `Error` trait.

```
fn print_error(mut err: &dyn Error) {
    while let Some(source) = err.source() {
        println!("error source: {}", source);
        err = source;
    }
}
```

You can find more details here too:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html

## References:

- Programming Rust, 2nd Edition (O'Reilly)
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Executive Summary

I previously posted a detailed answer to this question, however having used the dynamic dispatch approach for a week or so I wanted to post a slightly different take on the situation which I think will explain why dynamic dispatch is the correct approach with a simple to understand example, rather than a more complex and detailed explanation.

#### Scope of Applicability

This reasoning applies to both application and library code. I have previously seen it said that library code should return an enumeration of errors, whereas application code should use dynamic dispatch. I disagree with this, and suggest that dynamic dispatch is the "right" approach for both libraries and application level code.

#### Enumerations as Namespaces

Enumerations provide namespace behavior. This is what libraries are typically using them for, and it is wrong. I will explain why in more detail later, but the short answer is that modules provide namespaces, enums should not be used just for this purpose.

---

## Enum Example

A typical `enum` based approach looks like this:

```
// One Library / Module (Example)
enum MyModuleError {

    CalculationError {
        calculation_type: String
    },
    DataFormatError {
        // nothing here!
    },
}

// Another Library / Module (Abstract Example)
enum SomeLibraryError {

    ErrorType1 {
        data1: i32
    },
    ErrorType2 {
        some_data1: u64,
        some_data2: String,
    },
}

// All error types also need to implement these two traits:
impl std::error::Error for SomeLibraryError {}

use std::fmt;
impl fmt::Display for SomeLibraryError {

    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        
        match Self {

            ErrorType1(error_type_1) => {
                return write!(f, "something went wrong and the data was {}", error_type_1.data1);
            },
            // ...other enumerations...
    }
}
```

Code which produces these errors typically has a signature like this:

```
// no dynamic dispatch, because the error type is static
// rather than an aggregation of multiple possible types
fn some_function(argument: String)
    -> Result<OkType, SomeLibraryError>
{
    // code which might emit an error
}
```

or this, if we want to be able to dispatch errors of dynamic type

```
fn some_function(argument: String)
    -> Result<OkType, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>
{
    // code which might emit an error
}
```

The problem becomes clear when we try to use this.

```
fn error_consuming_function() {

    // a function which returns a dynamic error
    let result = some_function(something);

    // returned Result, so need to do something with it
    match result {

        Ok(success_value) => {}

        Err(error_value) => {

            if let Some(error) = error_value.downcast_ref::<SomeLibraryError>() {
                // error is of type SomeLibraryError, which is an enum
                // to do anything useful with it, we need to match on
                // the variant... this is clearly not the right pattern
                // *unless* all we want to do is log that an error occurred
            }

            else if let Some(error) = error_value.downcast_ref::<MyModuleError>() {
                match error {
                    CalculationError(calc_error) => { /* logic */ }
                    DataFormatError(data_format_error) => { /* logic */ }
                }
            }
            else { /* "catch all" */ }
        }

    }
}
```

In order to write any "useful" error handling / recovery logic, we are forced to write a match statement nested within a block which is already handling `downcast_ref`'s.

For something like a `CalculationError`, this might be an indication of a critical fault which we can't recover from. The only approach is to log and die.

On the other hand, a `DataFormatError` might be something we can recover from. For example, by ignoring that piece of data and continuing, while also logging a warning.

With that assumption, it doesn't make sense to use match at all, because we probably only want to write specific logic for a subset of error types, rather than an exhaustive list of types.

That's why dynamic dispatch is the better approach.

---

## Dynamic Dispatch Example

Let's "fix" our previous code, by removing the `enum`-ness ...

```
// One Library / Module (Example)
pub mod MyModuleError {

    pub struct CalculationError {
        calculation_type: String
    }

    pub struct DataFormatError {
        // nothing here!
    }
}

// Another Library / Module (Abstract Example)
pub mod SomeLibraryError {

    pub struct ErrorType1 {
        data1: i32
    }

    pub struct ErrorType2 {
        some_data1: u64,
        some_data2: String,
    }
}

// All error types also need to implement these two traits:
impl std::error::Error for ErrorType1 {}

use std::fmt;
impl fmt::Display for ErrorType1 {

    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {

        return write!(f, "something went wrong and the data was {}", self.data1);
        }
    }
}
```

The error handling code is simpler than before, and we will only "subscribe" to error types which we can handle.

```
fn error_consuming_function() -> Result<(), ...> {

    // a function which returns a dynamic error
    let result = some_function(something);

    // returned Result, so need to do something with it
    match result {

        Ok(success_value) => {}

        Err(error_value) => {

            if let Some(data_format_error) = error_value.downcast_ref::<DataFormatError>() {
                // log and continue...
            }
            else {
                // "catch all"
                // these are errors we can't implement recovery logic for
                // log and die or propagate to caller
                return error_value; // maybe
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Final Comments

Don't be put off by the seemingly complex error type of

```
dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static
```

as we can create a new type alias for this to simplify things

```
type GenericError = Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>
type GenericResult<T> = Result<T, GenericError>
```